# Can I use blowfish without the whole OpenSSL library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openssl

I am trying to compile networking `dll` project in Visual Studio 2010. In past, the original authors used the project to produce standalone `dll` file that could be distributed with the server it was used for. If I open their `dll`, I cans see this in dependency walker (the red items are not really an issue, the dll works):

[image: image description]

Now I tried to compile the project, but for both 32bit and 64bit (and 64bit is what I'm supposed to get to work) I produce a library that requires OpenSSL installed:

[image: image description]

Trying to put the `libeay32.lib` out of the build just causes link errors:

```
1>  Finished searching libraries
1>TTClient.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _BF_set_key
1>TTProtocol.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _BF_ecb_encrypt
1>D:\techsys\WebSightR220lib\Release\WebSightR220lib.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Comment: I have many times cherry picked from OpenSSL to get particular algorithms. It certainly works. A smaller alternative may be LibTomCrypt

Comment: @0xC0000022L As I'm really just trying to compile existing (huge) project, altering libaries seems like a problem. Actually, if I don't get any answer, I'm linking the 19MB static library.

Comment: My knowledge on openssl is limited, but is using a [separate implementation](https://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html) a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out linking seemingly huge static library is not as big problem when you want to use just a fraction of OpenSSH. The compiler will not just copy the library in your binary, it will just pick the parts that are needed.

Comment: Normally that will indeed be the case, if the **linker** (not the compiler) sees symbols not required and if there is support for LTO. But your question kind of implied that you work in an environment where that's *not* the case or that your configuration prevents that from working (e.g. Debug).

Comment: @0xC0000022L Well, when I did the same on linux the resulting `.so` library had 20MB, so it indeed depends on environment. Then again, I didn't even except to achieve compiling anything on linux, so I still consider myself lucky.

Comment: with or without symbols etc?! Thing is, on Windows these days symbols are always stored in a PDB file by default and you may enable MAP files if needed. But on Linux the symbols are by default stored inside the binary. You may use `objcopy` to extract them into a symbol file. That's to say your comparison more than likely is based on wrong assumptions about what's in that binary. Also assuming you built an `.so` *of* OpenSSL, that would be big. Because the linker has no way to know which symbols could be optimized out. Same for a `.dll` on Windows, though.